# Getting objects from JSON using cookies

Tags: json, cookies

I'm using a php script that contain some json files in this directory `content/languages/`
for example to call frensh language i must visit `domain.com/?=frensh`
Any tip to read the active language in cookie using js.

For example when i visit this link : `domain.com/?=english`
the langugae cookie change his value to english

Any ideas?

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines may help you with your idea

First insert this js functions next to yours

```
function readFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status === 200) {
                    callback(rawFile.responseText);
            }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Then like you says about the language cookie you can use this js line :

```
var dataJSON;
readFile("content/languages/"+getCookie("language")+".json", function(text) {
    dataJSON = JSON.parse(text); 
});
```

the results is like that `content/languages/english.json` if you have english value inside language cookie

The easy part comes next, if your json objects is like that

```
{
    "test": {
        "test1"                 : "test2",
     }
}
```

You can just write `dataJSON.test.test1` to print test2